# Locus in complex z-plane given eqn

Tags: complex-analysis, locus

I have the question:

$
\text{Find the locus in the complex }z\text{-plane that satisfies the equation: }
z-c=\rho\dfrac{1+it}{1-it}, \text{where }c\text{ is complex, }\rho\text{ is real, and }t\text{ is a real parameter that varies in the range }-\infty<t<\infty.
$
[1]

But I am unsure how to proceed - I haven't seen such a question with as many variables before; I don't really understand what should be the format of a solution. The only similar questions I can find I understand, but I can't translate that to what I should be doing here.

I realise that $c$ is essentially a transformation, so I assume that could be ignored to begin with, similarly I assume it could be assumed momentarily that $\rho=1$. But what more of an answer am I trying to find? The question already gives a condition for $z$, and wants a solution for $z$ too? Or have I totally misunderstood?

*1* - *Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering* - Ex3.4a

Comment: I meant "$c$ is a *translation*", which is of course a transformation. @michael-hardy - why the edit from "\frac" to "\dfrac"?

Comment: I thought \dfrac looked better in this case, but I don't insist on it if you want to change it back.

Comment: No no, I don't mind. Just curious; wasn't sure of the difference.

Comment: Theres no difference when the fraction is in a "displayed" setting and not within another fraction or matrix or other larger expression.  But when it's in an "inline" setting or within another fraction or a matrix or any of various other expressions, then the difference is this: $\frac ab$ versus $\dfrac ab$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\alpha=1+it$. Then

$$z-c=\rho\frac{\alpha}{\bar{\alpha}}.$$

It follows that

$$|z-c|^2=(z-c)(\bar{z}-\bar{c})=\rho\frac{\alpha}{\bar{\alpha}}\rho\frac{\bar{\alpha}}{\alpha}=\rho^2,$$

as $|\alpha|^2\neq 0$.

The desired locus is then

$$\mathcal L=\{z\in\mathbb C ~|~~ |z-c|=|\rho|\}. $$

Comment: So the solution to any locus-finding question should always have the form of a modulus of the complex number? $|z|=x$ is a locus, where $x$ is some complex number, perhaps with varying parameter?

Comment: Not necessarily; for example, the first quadrant in $\mathbb C$ is the locus $\mathcal L=\{z\in \mathbb C ~|~~arg z\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\}$. Reducing to an equation with the modulus can be an efficient approach in many cases, though.

Comment: I'm sorry to bring this back up after nearly a week, but I still don't understand why $$|z-c|^2=\rho\dfrac{\alpha}{\alpha*}\rho\dfrac{\alpha*}{\alpha}$$?

Comment: hallo! no problem! If a complex number, let us say, $w$ is given by the ratio $w=\rho\frac{\alpha}{\alpha*}$, with $\rho$ real and $\alpha$ complex, then its conjugate is $w*=\rho\frac{\alpha*}{\alpha}$. The product is then $|w|^2=ww*=\rho^2\frac{|\alpha|^2}{|\alpha|^2}=\rho^2,$ if $|\alpha|^2\neq 0$. Apply these considerations to $w=z-c$.

Comment: So $|w|^2=ww*$ is just an identity to remember? That's where I was confused. By the way, I would have upvoted your answer last week, but I need 15 rep and it was too soon to accept as answer.

Comment: exactly! If $w=a+ib$, then $w*=a-ib$ and $ww*=(a+ib)(a-ib)=a^2+b^2=|w|^2$. Please, feel free to upvote and flag the answer if you found it useful.

Comment: Oh, of course! Woops. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* The Möbius transformation $\dfrac{1+it}{1-it}$ maps the real line onto the set $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \colon\ |z|=1,\ z \ne -1\}$.